# Using Windows Command Line FOR command with quoted commas

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, cmd

I am trying to process a file containing values formatted like this:

```
 Token1    Token2            Token3    Token4
"ValueA", "ValueB, ValueC", "ValueD", "Value E"
```

(Headers added by me for clarity). I just want tokens 2 and 4.

The following command:

```
for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=," %a in (TestSource.txt) do @echo %a %b
```

Does work, but of course when Token2 contains a comma (as it does in the above example), it gets broken at that comma since the FOR command doesn't seem to know any better.

Are there any known workarounds to this limitation - I did quite a bit of looking into it and saw a "usebackq" command, but I don't think this is what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you break the string up by quote character only, and the just ignore strings containing just a comma.

Comment: A good idea - but one I failed on because I get a syntax error when using the " as a delimiter, even when trying to escape it (as in ^"). Otherwise, that'd work for me!

Comment: `for /f tokens^=3^,7^delims^=^" %f in (data.csv) do echo "%f", "%g"`

Comment: MC ND, very very nice. very nice. Never knew how to include a " in things. Now I do. Good general principle. Thanks.  Also, post this as an answer, not a comment, so it can be marked as answered.

Comment: @MCND Hey, have you considered what `David I. McIntosh` suggested?

Comment: @JoeDF, sorry, i had my inbox abbandoned. Of course, you and code' are right.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f tokens^=3^,7^ delims^=^" %f in (data.csv) do echo "%f", "%g"
```

There are two ways to include a "options" string for the `for` command. As it can include spaces and special characters, the first is the usual quoted string. But is some cases, it is not sufficient.

The second way is shown in the included code: escape all the separators in the options string.